# JavaFX Scene Builder launch issue

Tags: javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, scenebuilder, javafx-3d

I've been using Scene Builder for some time, but I can't launch it for the last few days. Nothing happens when I click on launch icon. I also can't launch it through NetBeans. I reinstalled it several times using both Gluon and Oracle installers, but still I can't launch it. I'm using Linux Mint 18 Sarah 64-bit.

Any ideas on this issue?

Comment: Where you have installed SceneBuilder in your system?
What is your version of SceneBuilder?

Comment: @Rahul Gupta opt/SceneBuilder